# user.nickname gives a URL instead of a nickname python GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, openid

I have the following code

```
 def get(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user:  # signed in already
        self.response.out.write("User Id =" + user.user_id() + " - User federated identity = " +  user.federated_identity() + " - User IdentityProvider = "+user.federated_provider() + " - User Email" + user.email() + "USer Nickname = " + user.nickname())
    else:     # let user choose authenticator
        self.response.out.write('Hello world! Sign in at: ')
        for name, uri in providers.items():
            self.response.out.write('[<a href="%s">%s</a>]' % (
                users.create_login_url(federated_identity=uri), name))
```

I tried using the google as well as yahoo as an open id provider, But whenever i try to access the user attributes such as user federated identity or user nickname it outputs URL instead of a nickname, Can anyone tell me if I am doing anything wrong here.

here is the output I am seeing

```
User federated identity = https://me.yahoo.com/a/JHqoh95mg8UqmFeDWlzSxKLW_SnNIOTlOcplbGQ

and user.nickname() also outputs this
```

P.S: I have already configured my application to use the open ID in the application dashboard and my code is working

Answer (score 2):

This is the documented behavior:

> nickname() Returns the "nickname" of the user, a displayable name. For
>   Google Accounts users, the nickname is either the "name" portion of
>   the user's email address if the address is in the same domain as the
>   application, or the user's full email address otherwise. For OpenID
>   users, the nickname is the OpenID identifier.

(from [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass#User_nickname))

Neither OpenID not the users API have a concept of a real nickname; if you want one, you'll have to ask the user for one and store it.

Comment: but I see the behavior on some other site where they get the user information